# Can you replace only the rubber in 2008 Jetta (Mk5) wipers?

Tags: vw, audi, windshield-wipers, jetta

Is it possible to replace only the rubber part of the windscreen wipers on a 2008 Jetta SE 2.5L?

I know that the original wipers are always made in Belgium (those sold in Ontario and in Northern California), and back in Ontario, Canada, I recall getting them from the dealer at a cheaper price than what similar but non-compatible wipers were available for at Walmart and Canadian Tire, but I'm not so lucky in Austin, TX.

According to [passatworld.com: Where do you all get your windshield wipers?](http://www.passatworld.com/forums/volkswagen-passat-b5-discussion/322677-where-do-you-all-get-your-windshield-wipers-i-dont-want-pay-$60-dealership.html), one can supposedly get Bosch Icons, but there are no details as to which (plus, my own experience at a Walmart in Canada in 2008/2010 is that no wipers from there fit my Jetta, has this since changed?).  Do Bosch Icons really fit?  Are they identical in size and dimensions to OEM?

It's also reported in the same thread that one can alternatively get [Bosch Aerotwin Wiper Refills $15 Shipped a PAIR](http://www.passatworld.com/forums/vendor-marketplace/198302-bosch-aerotwin-wiper-refills-%2415-shipped-pair.html) (now [18$](http://www.dubstopimports.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=wiper&Submit=)), however, there are not much instructions on how good of a fit it is (I didn't try hard, but it doesn't look like the blades are easily removable).

Some people also report that Audi dealerships sometimes have the wipers at a cheaper price -- are the wipers really the same, and how would you make sure to get compatible ones from an Audi dealer?  (The above 15$-a-pair link suggests that all VW Passat cars since mid-2002 has the same wipers, is that the case for Jetta and Audi, too?)

Comment: I'm sure you could do this. I've done it with different vehicles with varying degrees of success. The width is the main thing you need to pain attention to as there are two basic widths to wiper blades (where they mount the support piece). Personally, I like to replace the stock wiper blades with ones like the [Rain-X Latitude](https://www.rainx.com/product/wiper-blades/rain-x-latitude/) or the [Bosch Icon](https://www.boschautoparts.com/auto/wiper-blades/icon-wiper-blades). Ones which are a beam type (I think they call them). They work really well and cost about the same as you are talking.

Comment: @DucatiKiller, yeah, I know how that goes -- no, thanks! ^_^

Comment: To whomever put a close vote on this question, realize the OP is asking about fitment of different wipers, not about purchasing them. It is a valid question and on-topic, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

**You change the whole wiper**

Nobody makes just the rubber and sells it.  They fit it to various wiper frame components that fit different models and sell the to the owners of the vehicle the wiper frame was designed to fit.

If the package states it's for a particular vehicle, it's for that vehicle.  I haven't known Bosche to sell a wiper for a VW Rabbit when it's really for a Chevy Pickup Truck.

If you do not want to buy an OEM wiper you can goto an auto parts store and buy a aftermarket one.  They will have all kinds of them for you to choose from.

Asking about the variance in windshield wiper design from 2002 to the current date for a particular model of vehicle would require hours of research.  If you see a wiper and want to know if it fits your car you are doing your research in reverse.  You could lookup thousands of wipers and never find one that fits your car.  The appropriate way is to enter your car make/model/year regarding a manufacturer and see if they make one for your car.  You will reduce your workload a thousand fold.

Answer (score -2):

Wipers are made from rubber.  The quality of the rubber and its ability to squeegee the water off the glass is what you are actually buying.
You get what you pay for.  Generic vs Bosch...  Obviously one is better and will last longer before ripping or crumbling apart.
Wipers come in whats called an assembly that attach to the windshield wiper pole that is attached to the motor.  Sometimes there is a set of gears in between the motor and the two wipers.  The wipers assembly are easy to install and come with instruction.  Just replacing the wiper blades is the same as just replacing the wiper blade assembly.  The wiper pole. motor, gears, etc do now have to be messed with to replace the windshield wiper blades.
Most blades from what I know are all standardized no a days with a clip that has a level you push to remove the wiper blade assembly.  As I said in the store on the wiper blade package there is instructions.  There is also a book that has your cars make and model in it that will tell you what kind of wiper blades are compatible with your car.  Sometimes there is instruction in the front of that book as well. 
Good luck!